# getText().toString() vs (String) getText()

Tags: java, android

So, I've been looking at the getText() method and I've learned, that it returns a CharSequence.
So you can't just do this:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
String myString = myTextView.getText();
```

And instead, have to convert the returned CharSequence into a String by doing this:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
String myString = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

Here comes my question: Can't you just do this instead?:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
String myString = (String) myTextView.getText();
```

I've tried this in my code and it worked perfectly fine, but everyone seems to be using the first way.. So is there a problem I'm not seeing with my way of doing it? Or is it just a different way to do it and if so, what are the benefits of both ways?

Thanks for your answers in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So is there a problem I'm not seeing with my way of doing it?

It will crash with a `ClassCastException` if the `CharSequence` that is returned is not a `String`. For example, if you use `Html.fromHtml()` or other means of creating a `SpannedString`, and use that in the `TextView`, `getText()` will not return a `String`.